# How to go to next/previous CoreData record/managedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Basically what I want to do is to switch between CoreData elements (next/previous).
This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)plus
{

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

RootView *controller = (RootView *)navController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext =selectedPerson.managedObjectContext;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [controller.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSIndexPath* newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
controller.selectedNote = [controller.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
self.selectedPerson = controller.selectedNote;
self.title = self.selectedPerson.name;


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I want it to go to the next record in the TableView. So the selectedPerson from the detail View should display the next record

Comment: So display the new detail view controller?

Comment: The "next" function is called from the detail view controller. So basically I'm doing this from the detail view. I just need to update the info on the detail view.

Comment: So the problem is that you're creating a new detail instance from the storyboard instead of setting self.selectedPerson ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31708/discussion-between-ponyland-and-wain)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution myself. When I perform the segue from the RootVeiw to the DetailView I pass the row number to the DetailView. Then by using the code above, but slightly modified I am able to call the next record.